# Vb.net SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'myip' for table 'mytable'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

Hello how to connect to mysql database ?
Mysql database on my website but not connecting. I gived all permission

Connection succesful but not selecting.

> ERROR: SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'myip' for table 'mytable'

```
Dim DatabaseName As String = "mydatabase"
    Dim server As String = "myip"
    Dim userName As String = "myusername"
    Dim password As String = "mypass"
    Dim okuyucu As MySqlDataReader
    Dim baglanti As New MySqlConnection
    If Not baglanti Is Nothing Then baglanti.Close()
    baglanti.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)


        Try
            baglanti.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from database.chat where name='" & name.Text & "' and password='" & passwordbox.Text & "' "
            komut = New MySqlCommand(query, baglanti)
            okuyucu = komut.ExecuteReader
            Dim count As Integer
            count = 0
            While okuyucu.Read
                count = count + 1
            End While

            If count = 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Giriş bilgileri doğru !")

            ElseIf count > 1 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Giriş bilgileri fazladan var !")

            Else

                MessageBox.Show("Giriş bilgileri doğru değil !")
            End If

            baglanti.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            baglanti.Dispose()

        End Try
```

My connect code this is.

Comment: Please,  show your `CREATE USER` statement.

Comment: I was login mysql system